# mariadb-server install broken after Ubuntu upgrade to 13.04

Tags: ubuntu

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04, I couldn't install `mariadb-server`:

```
mariadb-server-5.5 : Depends: mariadb-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: mariadb-server-core-5.5 (>= 5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the command that works:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-5.5 mysql-common=5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal libmysqlclient18=5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal
```

Comment: This works in 12.04 , 12.10 and 13.04 (also LinuxMint 14). Apparently MariaDB is "sensitive" to anywhere the kernel has been updated past something like 3.5.0-25 which seems to affect the installation of MariaDB using a plain vanilla "sudo apt-get install mariadb-server"

Comment: does not work: `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-5.5 mysql-common=5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal libmysqlclient18=5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mariadb-server-5.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mariadb-server-5.5'
E: Version '5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal' for 'mysql-common' was not found
E: Version '5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal' for 'libmysqlclient18' was not found`

Answer (score 0):

I had mysql-server installed in a first time.

Using :

sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-5.5 mysql-common=5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal libmysqlclient18=5.5.30-mariadb1~quantal

got me an error about multiple package instance...

I had to manualy remove a duplicate libmysqlclient18 entry in /var/lib/dpkg/status (vi).